# Cant update app - Issue: Need login credentials for app review

Tags: android, google-play

The production version is available, but I'm having trouble updating my app on Google Play.

According to the Google Play email after review:

> Issue: Need login credentials for app review
> In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app.
> If users need credentials to access your app, please provide all appropriate credentials via Play Console.
> If you previously supplied credentials, please ensure that they have not expired.
> If your app normally uses 2-Step Verification (e.g. SMS verification), biometrics (e.g. a fingerprint or face scan) or a location-dependent password (e.g. geo-gate), please provide valid demo credentials that we can use instead.
> **If in-app content can’t be accessed after entering login credentials - We could not access in-app content due to app connection error.
>
> If login credentials are provided in non-English language - Please provide all appropriate credentials in English via Play Console.**

I was a little confused by these directions because I set up credentials in play console [Test - Pre Release Report - Settings - Test account credentials] and the credentials work on both emulate and real device.

In the email has no other information and I was not able to find a solution for this problem

Can anyone help please?

Comment: In this email they a screen shot, In the screen shot I see that they test with random credential information and not those I write into play console. Is the second time they send me this email with wtf screenshots..

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you're going to get an answer about your specific issue on here. However this line sticks out:

> We could not access in-app content due to app connection error.

Seems like they were not able to load the app data or something. Are you sure there are no issues with your app's backend services?

If there are, fix those. If there aren't, maybe just resubmit - it might have been a fluke. Finally, consult Google Play help for assistance: https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en#topic=3364260

Comment: Thank you for your help @dominicoder. On the backend issue, apparently it's all right because it responds correctly in the tests and even the iOS app works and is in production. As I said I'm having trouble updating the app.

Answer (score 0):

There's another place where app credentials can be provided in the Play Console: *Policy* (on the sidebar) > *App Content* > *App Access*.  From that page:

> If parts of your app are restricted based on login credentials, memberships, location or other forms of authentication, provide instructions on how to access them. Make sure that this information is kept up to date.
>
> Google may use this information to review your app. It won't be shared, or used for any other reason.

More details on the [*Prepare your app for review* help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?hl=en#app_access).